# How to unite 2 group boxes in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

I want to get text from group box 1 by clicking on the second one. How can I realize this feature via events? I'm not C# programmer.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        GroupBox GetGroupBox(string header)
        {
            GroupBox box = new GroupBox()
            {
                AutoSize = true
            };
            TableLayoutPanel layout = new TableLayoutPanel()
            {
                AutoSize = true
            };
            layout.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = header });
            box.Controls.Add(layout);
            for (uint i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
                layout.Controls.Add(new RadioButton() { Text = i.ToString() });
            return box;
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TableLayoutPanel layout = new TableLayoutPanel()
            {
                AutoSize = true
            };
            Controls.Add(layout);
            layout.Controls.Add(GetGroupBox("Group box 1"));
            layout.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = new string('-', 10) });
            layout.Controls.Add(GetGroupBox("Group box 2"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which test do you want to get from the groupbox and where do you want to use it in your program

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code, but I feel I should caution you here in that this is most likely not an elegant or scalable solution to the problem you face. I have added an event handler to the click event on the radio buttons - by adding the boolean addEventHandler variable set by default to false. The logic that handles the event is not the greatest but... I hope this helps.

```
GroupBox GetGroupBox(string header, bool addEventHandler = false)
        {
            GroupBox box = new GroupBox()
            {
                AutoSize = true,
                Name = header
            };
            TableLayoutPanel layout = new TableLayoutPanel()
            {
                AutoSize = true
            };
            layout.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = header });
            box.Controls.Add(layout);

            for (uint i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
            {
                var rbtn = new RadioButton() { Text = i.ToString() };
                if (addEventHandler)
                {
                    rbtn.Click += Form1_Click;
                }                
                layout.Controls.Add(rbtn);
            }

            return box;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TableLayoutPanel layout = new TableLayoutPanel()
            {
                AutoSize = true
            };
            layout.Controls.Add(GetGroupBox("Group box 1"));
            layout.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = new string('-', 10) });
            layout.Controls.Add(GetGroupBox("Group box 2", true));
            Controls.Add(layout);
        }

        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var group1Selected = this.Controls[0].Controls[0].Controls[0].Controls;
            var senderControl = (RadioButton)sender;

            if (senderControl.Parent.Parent.Name == "Group box 2")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < group1Selected.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (group1Selected[i] is RadioButton)
                    {
                        var rb = group1Selected[i] as RadioButton;
                        if (rb.Checked)
                        {
                            DialogResult rst = MessageBox.Show("Expected Message: " + rb.Text);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless otherwise specified , I would insert the content using the Toolbox from the Form1.cs[design].

You can access the Toolbox from the menu: View -> Toolbox.

From there you can drag and drop contents to your form. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/toolbox?view=vs-2017

The layout will be same as the one you have defined.

- Main container is a TableLayoutPanel (Name tableLayoutPanel1).
- Top Left GroupBox (Name groupBox1)
- Bottom Left GroupBox2 (groupBox2)
- Top Right TextBox  (Name textBox1 set as read only).

The Name property can be used to access the element from code behind.

Inside each group we will have the radio buttons defined as:

- radioButton1/2 for groupBox1
- radioButton3/4 for groupBox2

In the Form1.cs[design] by clicking on an element you will be able to change its properties. From below picture you can see how to access the text for radioButton1 groupBox1.

[image]

In the Form1.cs[design] by clicking on an element you will be able to add an event handler.

[image]

Once you add anything to the form , your code behind will reflect it.

Keeping that in mind your Form1 class will be needing just to handle the logic for when a click happen for radioButton3/4 groupBox2 and update the textBox1.text property accordingly.

The class will be as simple as:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
    }

    //as the radio buttons are in a group box they be mutually exclusive
    private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.radioButton3.Checked || radioButton4.Checked)
        {
            int val = this.radioButton1.Checked ? 0 : 1;
            textBox1.Text = String.Format("Expected msg:{0}", val);
        }
    }

    //as the radio buttons are in a group box will be mutually exclusive
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioButton3_CheckedChanged(sender, e);
    }
}
```